# Page Templates not Appearing in Kentico 13 Xperience Trail Version

Tags: kentico

I have Installed Kentico 13 Xperience Trail version it does not show me the Page Templates Except for the DancingGoatCore and i cannot use them but in Kentico 11 it was easy to create Kentico 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page templates in MVC5/.NET Core MVC are different from portal engine page templates. Those are two very different development models. In Xperience 13, you need to create your own page templates in your Core project. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/developing-websites/page-builder-development/developing-page-templates).

Answer (score 1):

Developers define the layout of these pages by preparing page templates in the code and content editors then create new landing pages based on these templates.
Content editors can also utilize page templates for creating pages with structured content. This can be useful, for example, if you have multiple possible layouts for product or article pages, and wish to allow editors to choose a suitable layout for each individual page.